# Cannot get angular ng-show or ng-hide to work inside directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-show, ng-hide

A webservice returns values back... if the values returned are == 'N' I want to hide the html element.  My problem is I cannot get ng-hide and ng-show to work inside the template.  I looked at the other simular questions and the fixes didn't work for me.  The confusing part is if I look at the rendered page the ng-show statement looks correct.

Here is my HTML:

```
<span five-star-img value="appHeader.star1"></span>
<span five-star-img value="appHeader.star2"></span>
```

Here is my directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('fiveStarImg', function() {
    return {
       template: '<img ng-hide="{{showStar(value)}}"/>',
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            value: '=',
            isize: '@'
        };                  


        scope.showStar = function(value) {
            if (value == 'N') {
               return true;
            } else {
               return false;
            }
        };
    };
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the `{{}}` when using `ng-hide` or `ng-show`.

`template: '<img ng-hide="showStar(value)"/>'` should work just fine

Comment: If I take out the {{}} brackets then inspect the rendered html it shows... "<img ng-hide="showStar()" class=ng-isolate-scope nghide" value="appHeader.star1" >

Comment: It must have been some type of caching issue on my end... I refreshed everything and it worked this time round!  thanks!